# Headers in JSON response

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I upgraded my project from Laravel 8 to Laravel 10 and got some weird JSON responses with headers. I thought it might be Postman but tried calling my API from Swift and got the same response. In my opinion, I missed something in the doc but can't figure out what.

**JSON response**

```json
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Wed, 19 Apr 2023 13:48:29 GMT

["test"]
```

However I want JSON only without headers.

```json
["test"]
```

demo code looks like this ( nothing more just this )

```php
response()->json(['sss']);
```

i fixed it with wrapping it to my Own Trait and call my own "response" with just json_encode for now but this is not correct :/

```php
json_encode(['success' => true])
```

Comment: Please, add request headers & show imported namespaces & please add screenshot with json response

Comment: i think you are missing the "Accept" header setted to application/json. In that way laravel will reply with a "valid" json

Comment: @InDevX i added headers in original post

Comment: @Jack i added headers in original post tryed "application/json" for both :/

Comment: och found it when i have "Content-Type" it returns this wierd things 

it works only when i remove "Content-Type" and keep "Accept" as "application/vnd.api+json"

Comment: Actually, u violate all the [rules of building json:api](https://jsonapi.org/format/), so it's better to use `application/json`, u can also not use Content-Type header, the request is smart enough to figure it out yourself

Comment: @InDevX problem is that iu need "Content-Type" to server accept my POST request with DATA cuz when i dont add it it will not read my request "raw" data, but when i add it i get invalid json as reply cuz this wierd response from Laravel

any idea whats may be wrong ?

Comment: @Patrick sadly no, but i found that if i do not send "Content-Type" header and use only "Accept" it works for GET/POST/..., also i use everywhere Resources as Return type maybe that helped too but i m not sure cuz i do not have response with ->``json()`` call